# SQL joins to display data without a foreign key to identify the data to retrieve

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, outer-join

I am trying to retrieve data of a trainer's clients from the `client` table that only applies to the user from the `personal_trainer` table. However, in the client table there is no foreign key to identify the trainer.

I have created two other tables `nutrition` and `training` which have both ClientID and personalTrainerID as foreign keys from their respective tables. I am wondering what is the sql statement to retrieve the data?

The logic i'm trying to create is: if a coach (personaltrainerID) has created a trianing/nutrition plan and assigned it to a client (clientID), the output is all the clients which have been assigned a training/nutrition plan.

The first `$query` is for a search function that works, the problem resides in the statement

```
$query = "SELECT * from client AS t1 LEFT JOIN nutrition_plan AS t2 ON personalTrainerID = clientID";
```

Full code:

```
    <?php
//code to search for a item from the database
// user can enter any character to search for a value from the db
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['ValueToSearch'];
    $query         = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE concat(`clientID`, `name`, `age`, `sex`, `weight`, `height`, `yearsExperience`, `goal`, `injuries`, 'email')LIKE'%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    } else {
```

$query = "SELECT * from client AS t1 LEFT JOIN nutrition_plan AS t2 ON personalTrainerID = clientID";
        $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }

```
//code to filter the db
function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect       = mysqli_connect('localhost:3308', 'root', '', 'fypdatabase');
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}
?>

<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)) {
    //display the details from the db in the table with option to delete or update entry 
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['clientID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['sex']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['weight']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['height']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['yearsExperience']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['goal']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['injuries']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
    <td> 
        <a href="?Delete=<?php echo $row['clientID']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Delete</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="updateClient.php?Edit=<?php echo $row['clientID']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Update</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `training_plan` (
          `trainingPlanID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `personalTrainerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `clientID` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `trainingType` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
          `exercise1` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nutrition_plan` (
  `nutritionplanID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `personaltrainerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `clientID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nutritionPlan` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `mealType` varchar(30) NOT NULL,

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `personal_trainer` (
      `personalTrainerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `location` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `sex` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `yearsExperience` int(11) NOT NULL,


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client` (
      `clientID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `sex` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `weight` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help here

Comment: May I ask what this is for? If this is just a pet project you can probably use nutrition or training as ugly bridge tables, as long as you won't have orphaned records. If this is going to be anything more than a pet project though you really need to rethink your data model.

Comment: This is a university project, its the last part of what i need to display from my db, so I just need to find a way to output it!

Comment: @GMB ive updated the question with the table structures, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a left join. Then you get data from both tables.

```
$query = "SELECT * from client WHERE email = (SELECT clientID FROM nutrition_plan WHERE personalTrainerID=clientID)";
```

change SQL to:

```
$query = "SELECT * from client AS t1 LEFT JOIN nutrition_plan AS t2 ON personalTrainerID = clientID";
```

Further more your query:

```
 $query = "select * from client WHERE concat(`clientID`, `name`, `age`, `sex`, `weight`, `height`, `yearsExperience`, `goal`, `injuries`, 'email')like'%".$valueToSearch."%'";
```

Will lead to slow execution on large tables. Do an OR `'name' like'%".$valueToSearch."%'"` etc. for every field and make sure the fields a properly indexed.

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks for your feedback! I have changed the SQL to the new code but it still is displaying me an error. The logic im trying to express is if a coach has created a training/nutrition plan and assigned it to a client, those clients will appear under the client list.

Comment: Use the coach_id in the client table if its a one tot one relation. Else use a third table to link the two tables.